# Spresense SDK のble_central に関して

Tags: spresense

Spresense SDK のble_central を動かそうとしており、ペアリングまでは出来たのですが、その後データを送る部分がサンプルに無さそうなのでご存じの方教えてください。

```c
static struct ble_gatt_central_ops_s ble_gatt_central_ops =
  {
    .write              = on_write,
    .read               = on_read,
    .notify             = on_notify,
    .database_discovery = on_db_discovery,
    .descriptor_write   = on_descriptor_write,
    .descriptor_read    = on_descriptor_read,
  };
```

ここのon_write 関数を実行すれば良いと思うのですが、トリガのかけ方が分かりません。

ちなみに BING AI の回答です。

> 申し訳ありませんが、Spresense SDK開発ガイド1によると、on_write関数は、BLE Centralのサンプルアプリケーションの中で、データを送信するための関数であることがわかります。しかし、トリガのかけ方については明確に記載されていないようです。また、Spresense SDKチュートリアル2にも詳細な情報がありませんでした。
>
> そのため、トリガのかけ方については、Spresense SDK開発者フォーラム3で質問することをお勧めします。

と言うことなのでこちらに質問させていただきました。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: すみません、自分の勘違いで on_write はデータを送った後に呼び出される関数でした。